# Error: Resource is not public. (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.ExpandedMenu')

Tags: android

While I am trying to apply `ExpandedMenu` theme it is showing this error

```
error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.ExpandedMenu').
```

Comment: In it's current form, this question is hard to answer. Could you add an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to your post?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use all themes (or any other resource) not defined as public explicitly by the system.
One way to check whether it is public or not it to try to autocomplete its name in the eclipse editor. If it doesn't show it is private.

One workaround is to copy all of it's attributes to your own definition and use it instead of the system private one. Sometimes it is not possible as it has too many dependencies on other private definitions.